# it is showing 403 forbidden when I call /myAccount endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

When I am trying to call any endpoint it is showing 403 forbidden error.
I created a customauthenticationprovider to implement role based authentication.

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

```
private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;
private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public CustomAuthenticationProvider(CustomerRepository customerRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
}

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    Customer customer = customerRepository.findByEmail(authentication.getName()).orElseThrow(() -> new CustomerNotFoundException(authentication.getName()));
    if(passwordEncoder.matches(authentication.getCredentials().toString(), customer.getPwd())) {
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                customer.getEmail(), customer.getPwd(), getGrantedAuthorities(customer.getAuthorities()));
    }
    else{
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid Credentials");
    }
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(Set<Authority> authorities) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Authority authority : authorities) {
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName()));
    }
    return grantedAuthorities;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
}
```

}

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
    requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");
    http.securityContext((context) -> context.requireExplicitSave(false))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS))
            .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(new CorsConfigurationSource() {
                @Override
                public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
                    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                    config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
                    config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
                    config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                    config.setMaxAge(3600L);
                    return config;
                }
            })).csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                    .csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler).ignoringRequestMatchers("/contact","/register")
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))
            .addFilterAfter(new CSRFCookieFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests)->requests
                    .requestMatchers("/myAccount").hasRole("USER")
                    .requestMatchers("/myBalance").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
                    .requestMatchers("/myLoans").hasRole("USER")
                    .requestMatchers("/myCards").hasRole("USER")
                    .requestMatchers("/user").authenticated()
                    .requestMatchers("/notices","/contact","/register").permitAll())
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

}

can anyone let me know what is the problem with my code, plea

Comment: Why not just enable DEBUG or TRACE logs and look for yourself?

Comment: @Toerktumlare, already did that and getting this.
Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
when I hit endpoint.